# Moving an LVM volume to another system

Tags: lvm

There are instructions how to move a volume group to another system (https://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/recipemovevgtonewsys.html), but can it be done with a single logical volume?
When I try to mark the volume as inactive with

```
$ sudo vgchange -an /dev/my-vg/home
  Invalid volume group name my-vg/home.
  Run `vgchange --help' for more information.
$ sudo pvscan
  PV /dev/sda5   VG my-vg       lvm2 [<297,85 GiB / 0    free]
  PV /dev/sdc2   VG my-vg       lvm2 [8,78 TiB / 0    free]
  Total: 2 [9,07 TiB] / in use: 2 [9,07 TiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
$ lsblk
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                     8:0    0 298,1G  0 disk 
├─sda1                  8:1    0   243M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                  8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5                  8:5    0 297,9G  0 part 
  ├─my--vg-root   254:0    0 148,4G  0 lvm  /
  ├─my--vg-swap_1 254:1    0    16G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─my--vg-var    254:2    0   133G  0 lvm  /var
  └─my--vg-tmp    254:3    0   380M  0 lvm  /tmp
sdb                     8:16   0   5,5T  0 disk 
└─sdb1                  8:17   0   5,5T  0 part 
sdc                     8:32   0   9,1T  0 disk 
├─sdc1                  8:33   0   320G  0 part 
└─sdc2                  8:34   0   8,8T  0 part 
  └─my--vg-home   254:4    0   8,8T  0 lvm  /home
```

Comment: What do you see when you type `sudo pvscan` or `lsblk`

Comment: I guess the solution is to move the volume to a new volume group, but can it be done without actually making a copy of existing volume?